# How to get substring after specific pattern in oracle

Tags: oracle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CustomerDebitCardLinkingWSBean>
<agentMsisdn>+923326088024</agentMsisdn>
<cardNumber>6233070000588011</cardNumber>
<channel>USSD</channel>
<customerMobileNumber>03345310550</customerMobileNumber>
<fromAgent>true</fromAgent>
<status>false</status>
</CustomerDebitCardLinkingWSBean>
```

this is a string, now i want to get substring of channel tag form start to end how is it possible?

Comment: can u simply code or suggest use of combination of substr and instr?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an xml parser, then it is possible with `regexp_replace`:

```
declare

  c varchar2(4000) := q'{
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CustomerDebitCardLinkingWSBean>
<agentMsisdn>+923326088024</agentMsisdn>
<cardNumber>6233070000588011</cardNumber>
<channel>USSD</channel>
<customerMobileNumber>03345310550</customerMobileNumber>
<fromAgent>true</fromAgent>
<status>false</status>
</CustomerDebitCardLinkingWSBean>
  }';

begin


  dbms_output.put_line(

      regexp_replace( c, 
        '.*<channel>(.*)</channel>.*',
        '\1',
        1,
        1,
       'n'
      )

  );

end;
```

Although I *strongly* advice against such a use.

For completness' sake, here's a solution to do it with Oracle's `XMLType`:

```
declare

  xml XMLType := XMLType(q'{
<CustomerDebitCardLinkingWSBean>
<agentMsisdn>+923326088024</agentMsisdn>
<cardNumber>6233070000588011</cardNumber>
<channel>USSD</channel>
<customerMobileNumber>03345310550</customerMobileNumber>
<fromAgent>true</fromAgent>
<status>false</status>
</CustomerDebitCardLinkingWSBean>
  }');


  channel varchar2(20);

begin

  select extractvalue(xml, 'CustomerDebitCardLinkingWSBean/channel') into channel from dual;

  dbms_output.put_line(channel);

end;
/
```